# Can we select JmsTemplate dynamically on the basis of MessageHeaders while using outbound jms adapter?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

I have created 2 `jmsTemplate` Bean to be able to handle sending message to `Solace Queue` and `Solace Topic` accordingly, now when I am passing the message on the `exampleChannel` below I want to if it is possible for MessageHandler to pick the jmsTemplate dynamically ? if I pass the message with `MessageHeader` lets say `destinationType=Topic/Queue`

Below are the configurations

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("topic")
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("queue")
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate1;

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "exampleMessageChannel" )
    public MessageHandler archiveOutboundHandler() {

        /*
         I need to select between jmsTemplate & jmsTemplate1 on the basis on header 
         information. 
         **/
        JmsSendingMessageHandler messageHandler = new JmsSendingMessageHandler(jmsTemplete);
        messageHandler.setDestinationExpression(new FunctionExpression<Message<?>>(m->m.getHeaders().get("destination")));
        return messageHandler;
    }
```

Is it possible ? or is there a better way of doing this ?

**Update 1:**

After @Artem suggested to change the implementation of destinationExpression to return Destination, I did this

```
    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outMessageChannel" )
    public MessageHandler archiveOutboundHandler() {
        JmsSendingMessageHandler messageHandler = new JmsSendingMessageHandler(jmsTemplate);
        messageHandler.setDestinationExpression(new FunctionExpression<Message<?>>(message -> {
            if((Objects.equals(message.getHeaders().get("destinationType"), "topic"))){
               return (Topic) () -> (String) message.getHeaders().get("destination");
            }else{
                return (Queue) () -> (String) message.getHeaders().get("destination");
            }
        }));
        return messageHandler;
    }
```

I am getting below exception

```
$$Lambda$821/1572602632 cannot be cast to com.solacesystems.jms.SolDestination)
```

**Update 2**

I was able to resolve the destination using `JndiDestinationResolver`

As Artem suggested to use `BeanFactoryDestinationResolver` it was not feasible for me to use as there were too many destinations and `BeanFactoryDestinationResolver` required specific beans to be created for each destination.

I had already configured `JndiDestinationResolver` so I just had to inject `DestinationResolver` to resolve destination.

below is the snippet,

```
@Autowired
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

@Autowired
private DestinationResolver destinationResolver;

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "exampleChannel" )
public MessageHandler jmsOutboundHandler() {
    
    JmsSendingMessageHandler messageHandler = new JmsSendingMessageHandler(jmsTemplate);
    messageHandler.setDestinationExpression(new FunctionExpression<Message<?>>(message -> {
        if(message.getHeaders().get("dest_type").equals("topic")){
               return destinationResolver.resolveDestinationName(null,(String) message.getHeaders().get("dest"),true);
            
        }else{
               return destinationResolver.resolveDestinationName(null,(String) message.getHeaders().get("dest"),false);
        }
    }));
    return messageHandler;
}
```

Thanks for all the inputs, I will raise GH issue to include pubsub feature in `DynamicJmsTemplate`

Comment: Why do you need different `JmsTemplate` instances? It is a stateless component which can be shared for different use-cases. So, you simply can produce to the queue, as well as to topic. Please, elaborate more about your situation with two different `JmsTemplate` instances

Comment: I was looking at some spring documentation, by default spring uses pubsub as false, and if we want to send message on the topic that needs to be set to 'true' thats why I created 2 beans one for topic and other for queue, can you please tell me how we can use the same instance so that it'll produce on queue as well as topic

Comment: @ArtemBilan No JmsTemplate isn't stateless as it shares several properties accross consumers (default queue, converter, QoS, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what you mean.

It has a logic like this:

```
protected Destination resolveDestinationName(Session session, String destinationName) throws JMSException {
    return getDestinationResolver().resolveDestinationName(session, destinationName, isPubSubDomain());
}
```

Where a default `DynamicDestinationResolver` has it like this:

```
if (pubSubDomain) {
        return resolveTopic(session, destinationName);
    }
    else {
        return resolveQueue(session, destinationName);
    }
```

As a workaround consider to have your `destinationExpression` to be evaluated to the `javax.jms.Destination` instance instead of their plain names. This way you won't be tied to the `pubSubDomain` property.

There is also a `BeanFactoryDestinationResolver` to resolve a provided name into a `Destination` bean from the application context.

At the same time I'm asking you for raising a GH issue for adding a `pubSubDomain` support into `DynamicJmsTemplate` API. So, you will be able to determine `pubSubDomain` according an expression evaluation in that `JmsSendingMessageHandler`.

Comment: Thanks Artem !  I have edited the question with the changes, seems I am missing on the basics

Comment: `cast` ? No, it cannot be cast so easy. You have really create an instance of `SolDestination`. Or in that expression content or upfront before sending to this endpoint. It might even better to think about having beans for those destinations if Solace allows us to do that. I used that approach in combination with the `BeanFactoryDestinationResolver` in WebSphere against its JNDI.

Comment: Thanks for you Input, Using `BeanFactoryDestinationResolver`  was not feasible for me as I was not using static configuration and `BeanFactoryDestinationResolver` required specific bean for all those destination needs to be created. Instead I was already using `JndiDestinationResolver` so I made use of the same to resolve the destination added snippet for the same.